# Trying to make a label update in tkinter from a random variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a virtual dice within Python and using tkinter for the GUI, basically generating a random number form 1-6 but i cannot get the label to update with the result of the 'roll'. Can anyone help me please? This is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import*
import random

class Application(Frame):
    result = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label1 = Label(self)
        self.label1["text"] = "You rolled a " + str(self.result)
        self.label1.grid()

        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Roll again?")
        self.button1["command"] = self.rd()
        self.button1.grid()

    def rd(self):
        result = random.randint(1, 6)
        self.label1.config(text= "You rolled a " + str(self.result))




root = Tk()
root.title("Dice")
root.geometry("100x50")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    self.button1["command"] = self.rd()
```

On this line, you're assigning the *result* of `self.rd` to the command. `rd` returns None, so you're effectively saying that the button has no command at all. Try:

```
    self.button1["command"] = self.rd
```

Additionally, on these lines:

```
    result = random.randint(1, 6)
    self.label1.config(text= "You rolled a " + str(self.result))
```

You create a variable `result`, but then config the label with `self.result`, which is completely independent of `result`, so it will always display 0. Try:

```
    result = random.randint(1, 6)
    self.label1.config(text= "You rolled a " + str(result))
```

Or, if you want to keep track of the last derived result for other purposes,

```
    self.result = random.randint(1, 6)
    self.label1.config(text= "You rolled a " + str(self.result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made two errors here:

1. You assign the *result of a call* to `self.rd` (which is `None`) as the button's command, not the method itself; and
2. You assign the random dice roll to the local name `result`, **not** the class attribute `self.result`.

The correct code would include:

```
self.button1["command"] = self.rd 
                               # ^ note parentheses '()' removed
```

and:

```
def rd(self):
    self.result = random.randint(1, 6)
  # ^ note 'self.' added
    self.label1.config(text= "You rolled a " + str(self.result))
```